# J2SE: No data found for VIEWS (JDBC)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying obtain data from views in ORACLE DB from J2SE application. For tables it retrieves rows, for views not. From SQL developer or system API data are visible, not from ODBC driver in J2SE application.

Is there any solution?

```
            String query = "select * from APPS.WSH_DELIVERABLE_TRIPS_V";

        PreparedStatement prep = Database.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            dataFound = true;
            textInfo.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getString(1)));
        }
```

When I change object name for other table/view it works fine (for example APPS.XXNCH_PIM_ITEM_V)

Strange is following, I tried query in SQL developer under same creditials (it works fine). Is JDBC driver corrupted for same objects?

Comment: J2SE became out of date over ten years ago. time to update your material

Comment: Is it visible with same user? Does it execute same query as you test on SQL developer? How you fetch the data? Do you use any framework? Maybe a code example? Did you debug? Can you see in server logs same executed query with the same params?

Comment: Stultuske: I know, I use it for RF Guns.

HRgiger: It is visible (no error about not existing table) - but there are not data for JDBC in J2SE. Yes exactly same query like SQL Developer. 

I use:
Connection
PreparedStatement
ResultSet

It works for all tables in system, not for views.
I have no access to server logs.

Comment: J2SE is an outdated term, it is either simply called Java, or maybe Java SE. But to the question: show the code.

Comment: "I have no access to server logs" => You need to simulate same env. in your local, simply write a small application that using same JDBC settings and debug in your local env. this view query

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the Java code you use to retrieve that information.

Comment: I just edited question. I tried to google it over 5 hours without any good point how to workaround it.